# ListView onClick Handler

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have an application where my design has 2 tabs. Tab1 has listview, I want each listitem on click to give a detail. But on theclick of item the tab designs and Tab2 data and design must remain same. So can should i start new intent with same design ?? IF yes should copy the code of design or should i make separate class for Tab View design and each Tab??

Or is there a way i can update the view of tab 1 ?? And also if i update the view of tab1 will pressing on back button take user to previous view or to startup of my application???

Code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

    TabHost tabhost=(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabhost.setup();

    tabhost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.divider2);

    TabSpec spec1=tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

    TabSpec spec2=tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

    tabhost.addTab(spec1);
    tabhost.addTab(spec2);             

    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setBackgroundDrawable(null);


    String values[]={"Apple", "IOS", "Google", "Android"};

    ListView listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewstyle,R.id.textlist, values);
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.textlist2);           

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            //I want to update Tab1 now using this function and change into a completely new layout

                    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.frame2text);
            tv.setText(data);

            frm1=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame1);
            frm2=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame2);

            frm1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            frm2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            islast=true;

        }
    });               

}
```

My android_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

<TabWidget 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:tabStripEnabled="false"     
android:background="@drawable/tabwstyle"/>

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/tab1">     

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" 
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frame2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/testtxt"
            android:id="@+id/frame2text"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/tab2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/testtxt"/>

</LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

logcat output

```
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.example.pain.killer.PainKiller$1.onItemClick(PainKiller.java:64)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-06 18:50:06.990: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my listviewststyle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<!--      <ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/img"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"        
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >  
</ImageView> -->

<TextView  
android:id="@+id/textlist"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textSize="16dp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:drawablePadding="6dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:typeface="serif"/>

<!--    <TextView 
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-310dp"
    android:id="@+id/textlist2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/testtxt"/> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check now, i have added code and written my doubt

Comment: please visit here http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

Comment: he has just explained how to make tabs !! I have already made tabs. I have doubt on handling click on list view items

Comment: ok please provide your activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one another FrameLayout in same xml with new Layout you want.
Set that framelayout visibility GONE.

Now on item click of listview item setvisibility of second framelayout is VISIBLE and first framelayout is GONE.

Update your above code with this

```
FrameLayout fm1,fm2;
boolean islast;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);     
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

TabHost tabhost=(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabhost.setup();

tabhost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.divider2);

TabSpec spec1=tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

TabSpec spec2=tabhost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

tabhost.addTab(spec1);
tabhost.addTab(spec2);             

tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setBackgroundDrawable(null);
tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setBackgroundDrawable(null);


String values[]={"Apple", "IOS", "Google", "Android"};
 fm1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fm1);
fm2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fm2);

ListView listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewstyle,R.id.textlist, values);
//ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.textlist2);           

listview.setAdapter(adapter);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        //I want to update Tab1 now using this function and change into a completely new layout
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ITEM CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            fm1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fm2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            islast = true;

    }
});               
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (islast) {
        fm1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fm2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        islast = false;
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
    }else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:paddingTop="60dp"
android:id="@+id/tab1">     

//Update HERE below given code

</LinearLayout>
```

update your linear layout for tab1 with this below code.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fm1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fm2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: my application is crashing when i click on any item !! The code i wrote inside setOnItemClickListener is :

    String data=((TextView) view).getText().toString();
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1_textview);
    TextView txtview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textupdate);
    txtview.setText(data);


What i did was , add another Linear layout to the current frame. and replaced spec1 with that layout. Is it wrong?? + I want to keep same  tab2 no change is going to occur in it

Comment: Try above code this will work fine without affecting second tab

Comment: i tried the above code, it gives error!! actually if i dont write anything in the function : onItemClick it works, else as soon as i try to even create a Toast notification, It crashes, is my function implementation wrong ??

Comment: post your code because my side its working.In my post code above there is Toast message as well as set layout property and it's working fine.

Comment: it is the same as to what i have posted , im using android 2.2

Comment: But there is no code in onItemClick from your side than how your application crashed on item click.I am using your code which you post above and that's working fine.Only i adding Toast and framelayout visibility to onItemClick. And it's working. Replace your code with my code in both xml as well as java and than check it's working or not?

Comment: also i reach to this part after an initial screen where in the user clicks on a button and reaches here

Comment: ive added logcat above please see , n i've edited the code too

Comment: My side it's working properly. try to clean build your project and than run.

Comment: naah the problem is being  caused due to my listextstyle.xml , when i remove a listview element from it works fine. If i add it, i get error, can you think of a reason why??

Comment: i have just look above, i've added it

Answer (score 0):

Update the `ArrayList` according to your needs and use `notifydatasetchanged()` for tab1 to update the listitems.

Comment: can you explain or give me a link. + I want to change the list view into normal Text View or completely different layout from before

Answer (score 0):

Hello Brooklyn your list item click is working fine.

to solve your problem you have to use

> TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup

to handle multiple activities under the same tab.

> you can go through [here](https://github.com/pjq/ActivityGroupDemo)
>
> or You can look the other way Fragments with tabs [here](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/)
>
> > 

i hope it helps you.

Comment: can you help me to explain a little more. I cant seem to make head or tail of this :( sorry

Comment: I'm getting an error for the onItemClickListener :(
<br/> what i did was attempt to start a new intent im getting error